# Recompilation Issue When Pushing To Production

Tags: apex, deployment, validation, error, compile-error

I have a class that I updated and am pushing to production.

When I validate, I am getting this error for all 300 classes in production:

> line -1, column -1: Dependent class is invalid and needs recompilation: Class CommunitiesSelfRegController : Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void automatedClass(List) from the type AutomatedCreditStart

The class I am updating is `AutomatedCreditStart.cls` and the method I updated is `automatedClass(List<Id>)`. I updated the name of the class and some of the logic within the class, but did not change the parameters or list datatype.

--> currently in production:

```
public class AutomatedCreditStart {
    @InvocableMethod
    public static void automatedClass(List<Id> oppStatementsIn) {
```

--> updates trying to push to production:

```
public class AutomatedCreditStart {
    @InvocableMethod
    public static void createCreditReviews(List<Id> oppStatementsIn) {
```

The test class that belongs to `AutomatedCreditStart.cls` has passing coverage.

`AutomatedCreditStart.cls` is on version 41 in production and the newly updated class is also on v41.

The method does exist, the signature is correct, is this actually a recompilation issue? Do I actually need to recompile all of my classes? I do not want to do this as some of the classes will break if I update them. I can't figure out what the actual issue is. I doubt it is a recompile issue because I am not changing versions.

Comment: So you changed the method name? Did you leave the old method name in? Did you update all references to this method?

Comment: I did change the method name and took out the old method name. I updated all references except for one instance in a test class. This is where the issue was, thank you for prompting thought on this, I just pushed with the appropriate updates and it passed validation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change the method name, you have two choices:

1. Replace the old method name with the new one. If you do so, you need to **update every class which makes use of this method to replace the name there as well**.
2. Leverage method overloading to simplify the cut over. In this way, you can start the move to your new method name without making it all or none.

   ```
   public static void myNewMethod(List<Id> param)
   {
       // do stuff
   }
   public static void myDeprecatedMethod(List<Id> param)
   {
       myNewMethod(param);
   }
   ```